On the integrand of the infinite dimensional stochastic integral
Let $W$ be a $Q$-Wiener process taking values in a Hilbert space $U$, $U_0:=Q^{\frac{1}{2}}U$ be the reproducing kernel Hilbert space of $W$.
In [Da prato and Zabczyk,2014], it states that the admissble integrand with respect to $W$ should be
those $L^2(U_0,H) $-valued stochastic processes $\Phi$ such that $\mathbb{E}\int_0^tTr[(\Phi(s)Q^{\frac{1}{2}}(\Phi(s)Q^{\frac{1}{2}})^*]ds<\infty, \forall t\in [0,T]$.
My question is: since $W$ is a $U$-valued Wiener process, it is natural to require that the integrand $\Phi$ should take values (at least) in $L(U,H)$, instead of $L(U_0,H)$ (afterall, $U_0$ may be smaller that $U$).
How should I understand this?

The way I understand it, is that not $\Phi$ is the object of interest, but $\Phi(s) Q^{1/2}$. Here, $\Phi(s) Q^{1/2}\in L(U,H)$, hence $\Phi(s) \in L(U_0,H)$. I struggled a lot with these things myself, so maybe sections 1.1.2 and 1.1.3 of my thesis can be useful for you. https://scholarlypublications.universiteitleiden.nl/handle/1887/136538

@C.Hamster Thank you, and I will have a study!

At the beginning, the integrand was actually defined as $L(U,H)$ valued process. You can see some early works of Ichikawa and Ruth F. Curtain.
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X82900415
$L^{2}(U_0,H)$ valued processes is a generalization since $L(U,H) \subseteq L^{2}(U_0,H)$. Also, $L(U,H)$ is not a very "nice" space when equipped with the bounded linear operator topology since it's not separable. By contrast, $L^{2}(U_0,H)$ is separable.
